# SQL: Showing columns from 2 tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a resource and an orders table in my SQL Database and I have the following SQL query:

```
Select resource.id, resource.name from resource
inner join orders on orders.res_id = resource.id 
where orders.markup < 1000 and 
resource.id = 100
```

This works fine and shows the filtered ID and NAME field in my view. However, I would also like to see the orders.markup column in the view. I tried the following:

```
Select resource.id, resource.name, orders.* from resource, orders 
inner join orders on orders.res_id = resource.id 
where orders.markup < 1000 and 
resource.id = 100
```

This fails with:

```
ORA-00904: "RESOURCE"."ID": invalid identifier
```

Comment: Never use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select resource.id, resource.name, orders.markup from resource
inner join orders on orders.res_id = resource.id 
where orders.markup < 1000 and 
resource.id = 100
```

Comment: Mark as answer then. Thx

Answer (score 1):

there's a mistake in your code - you use **resource, orders** same time as inner join... remove **,orders** from your query or vice versa - remove inner join

sample:

```
create table "resource" (id integer, name varchar2(50));
create table orders (res_id int, markup integer, name varchar2(50));

select res.id, res.name, orders.* 
from "resource" res 
inner join orders on orders.res_id = res.id
where orders.markup < 1000 and 
res.id = 100
```